# Toggle shift key using F2 for vim

Tags: unix, vim

What commands can I put in .vimrc file so that, when I press F2, vim will take it as shift key pressed and it won't release until F2 is pressed again.

Answer (score 1):

Without any clarification, the reader may assume that `vim` is running in a *terminal emulator*.  For that case, only complete key press/release events are seen by `vim`.  You cannot do what was asked in that configuration.

If you are talking about `gvim` (any of the GUI configurations), then it would be possible for vim's developers to provide some binding which is triggered by separate key *press* and *release* events.  However, its documentation (such as *[Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29)*) is silent on that aspect.  Probably the existing program cannot do this.